# Select Date Range Join

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, timespan, date-range

I have a query which selecting between '01/05/2017' and '05/05/2017' and returns rows like

```
Date       EmployeeCode  EmployeeName  EntryTime   ExitTime
01/05/2017     10             a           08:00       18:00
02/05/2017     10             a           08:30       17:30
03/05/2017     10             a           08:30       17:30
03/05/2017     10             c           07:30       19:30
04/05/2017     10             c           09:30       18:30
05/05/2017     10             c           08:30       15:30
```

But I want to see like

```
Date       EmployeeCode  EmployeeName  EntryTime   ExitTime
01/05/2017     10             a           08:00       18:00
02/05/2017     10             a           08:30       17:30
03/05/2017     10             a           08:30       17:30
04/05/2017     10             a             -          -
05/05/2017     10             a           08:30       17:30
01/05/2017     10             c             -          -
02/05/2017     10             c             -          -
03/05/2017     10             c           07:30       19:30
04/05/2017     10             c           09:30       18:30
05/05/2017     10             c           08:30       15:30
```

> I tried join with date range but could not get result as I want.

```
     WITH mycte AS
 (
  SELECT CAST('2017-05-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 <= CAST('2017-05-05' AS DATETIME)
 )

 SELECT  
 DateValue
 FROM mycte
```

> How can I get this rows ?

Comment: do you have a `dates` table in your database?

Comment: Are these the dates you are looking for? [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Join to a calendar table... there are 100's of examples.

Comment: I don't have dates table @vkp.But I can add.

Comment: dates are for an exaple.I will send parameter for dates @SqlZim

Comment: I tried but couldnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate your dates and `cross join` your employees, then `left join` to your entry/exit times table.

This uses a stacked cte to generate the dates:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170401'
declare @thrudate date = '20170505'
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select d.[Date], e.EmployeeCode, e.EmployeeName, t.EntryTime, t.ExitTime
from dates d
  cross join (
    select EmployeeCode, EmployeeName
    from Employees
    ) e
  left join TimeCard t
    on t.Date = d.Date
   and t.EmployeeCode = e.EmployeeCode
```

---

Better yet, you can create a dates table.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK  cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Your answer was not completely what I want but mostly it was.You guided me.Thank you.